# I need to define a function that determines the matching letters between words and returns back as a integer

Tags: python

I need to define a function that compares words which determines matching letters before printing a message to tell the user how many letters of the guessed word are correct. It also needs to return back to the program as an integer. The function should return the number of matching letters and should not print anything

I am unsure how to do this?

def compareWords(word1, word2):

Comment: Please show what you have tried to implement from your research and what didn't work.

Comment: def compareWords(password,chosenWord):
                counter = 0
                empty = [0]
                if password[0,1,2,3,4,5] == chosenword[0,1,2,3,4,5]:
                    counter = counter + 1

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job, it loops over both the words and compares every letter pair.

```
def compareWords(word1, word2):
    count = 0

    for char1, char2 in zip(word1, word2):
        if char1 == char2:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Comment: What about chars that aren't at the same index?

Comment: @sobek I assumed that the "matching letters" meant same letters in the same position.

Comment: this is the function i have implemented in code
 def compareWords(password,chosenWord):
                counter = 0
                empty = [0]
                if password[0,1,2,3,4,5] == chosenword[0,1,2,3,4,5]:
                    counter = counter + 1

Comment: @gunpowdercairn your function is quite weird. P.S. feel free to mark my answer as accepted if you feel like it answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

Naive method of solving this problem is to compare each character in *word2* with *word1*

Sample Code :

```
def compareWords(word1,word2):
    count = 0
    for ch in word2:
        if ch in word1:
           count=count+1
    return count
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: This won't work. `in` will simply return True if the letter is present, regardless of its position in the strings

Comment: yes,user needs to count the no of matching characters in both strings

Comment: I understand, and I'm saying this answer _does not_ compare characters by their position in the string